# Output: "Array"

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

I added a table in the database which collects names through a form.
I want to output the latest entered name on a different page than the one which contains the form.

In order to print the data I added the following php code through a WPcode shortcake.
The used code is:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( 'besuchername FROM besucher');
{
echo $result;
}
```

However, the only output I get is: Array

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Loop thru the results array.  See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#examples-5

Comment: `echo` cannot print complex data types. Use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to print out an array for debugging purposes.

Comment: I tried but still got array... 

global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT besuchername FROM besucher ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');

{
 print_r('$result') ;
}

Comment: ok. I made some progress :)

Comment: global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM besucher LIMIT 1');
{
 foreach($results as $result) {
  echo $result->besuchername.'<br>';
 }
    
}
?>

displays all names, but I only need to print the latest entry. How to do this?